# Heat Equation - please help

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

[image]

I've been studying the heat equation and separation of variables  and came accross this practise question - I wanted to know if I use the same method I use usually is correct i.e. choose a constant and equate to three different cases k^2, -k^2 and k=o.

please correct if me I am wrong, thank you

Comment: That's the right way to do it. I personally take $\lambda > 0$, $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda < 0$ but it's the same really.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Look for a solution of the form:
$$
u(x,t)=f(t)\sin\frac{\pi x}{2a}+g(t)\sin\frac{7\pi x}{2a},
$$
which if you plug into the equation you get
$$
u_{t}-Du_{xx}=\left(f'(t)+D\frac{\pi^2}{4a^2}f(t)\right)\sin\frac{\pi x}{2a}+\left(g'(t)+D\frac{49 \pi^2}{4a^2}g(t)\right)\sin\frac{7\pi x}{2a}=0,
$$
which provides the following to ordinary differential equations
$$
f'(t)+D\frac{\pi^2}{4a^2}f(t)=0,
$$
and
$$
g'(t)+D\frac{49 \pi^2}{4a^2}g(t)=0.
$$
Then

$f(t)=f(0)\,\mathrm{e}^{-tD\pi^2/4a^2}=10\,\mathrm{e}^{-tD\pi^2/4a^2}$,

$g(t)=g(0)\,\mathrm{e}^{-49tD\pi^2/4a^2}=20\,\mathrm{e}^{-49tD\pi^2/4a^2}$.

Note that

$$
u(x,t)=10\,\mathrm{e}^{-tD\pi^2/4a^2}\sin\frac{\pi x}{2a}+20\,\mathrm{e}^{-49tD\pi^2/4a^2}
\sin\frac{7\pi x}{2a},
$$
satisfies the PDE and all the conditions: initial & boundary.

Comment: Could the solution not be in the form X(x)T(t) ?

Comment: Theoretically it could, but for such a problem and initial data, you are pretty much instructed to look for a solution of this form.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found out what my a is from the boundary conditions but how would I work out B with the boundary condition being a derivative (I have never come across the boundary condition being a derivative)

Comment: Don't worry about it, as the initial data you are given DO satisfy this kind of BCs - see updated solution.